# Sending an entire log file to graylog using fluentd

Tags: fluentd, graylog2

Is there a way to send an entire log file with an inconsistent format to Graylog's web interface as the message field using Fluentd?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding **Graylog**, it does not require any specific log format. A pattern is needed only if you want to parse it and separate the fields for easy querying and statistics.

Based on the [Fluentd plugins page](https://www.fluentd.org/plugins/) there is this plugin named [Fluentd GELF output](https://github.com/bodhi-space/fluent-plugin-gelf-hs) that is able to format and output **Fluentd** logs to **Graylog**.

I am not really into **Fluentd** therefore I cannot give you much details about the configuration of such plugin. But based on the `README` of the project it seems straight forward.